# Does ObservableValidator work in properties which are classes

Tags: .net-core, maui, windows-community-toolkit, maui-community-toolkit

I have a Maui app with a view model. The ViewModel has the following property:

```
[ObservableProperty]
public UserAccountDTO userAccount = new UserAccountDTO();
```

UserAccountDTO has the following property:

```
   public partial class UserAccountDTO: ObservableValidator
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Firstname required")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Text length is maximum 10!")]
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string firstName;
    }
```

I have the firstName bound to an Entry.

In the VM, when I call ValidateAllProperties() I don't get any errors coming back from this class. I.e. if FirstName is blank HasErrors is still false.

```
[RelayCommand]
private async void CreateAccountPressed()
{
    ValidateAllProperties();
    string Error = string.Empty;

    if (HasErrors)
            Error = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetErrors().Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Source code how you call it.

Comment: Just added that information to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the ObservableValidator for the firstName, you should add the get and set method to the Firstname..

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Firstname required")]
[MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Text length is maximum 10!")]
[ObservableProperty]
  public string FirstName
    {
        get => this.firstName;
        set => SetProperty(ref this.firstName, value, true);
    }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, but either way your code doesn't compile.